# C++ error when putting typedef statements inside class for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, class, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a doubly linked list.

I have 3 typedef statements in my class.

When compiled I get the error "'reference' does not name a type". If I move them under my include statements, this error disappears but new ones arise, such as 'Node' not being declared in my main scope. I am not sure where each of these typedef statements need to go in order to get my program functioning properly. I have included the default constructor as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class linkedlist
{
public:

    typedef int element_type;
    typedef element_type& reference;
    typedef const element_type& const_reference;
    linkedlist();
    ~linkedlist();
    bool empty() const;
    void clear();
    reference back();
    const_reference back() const;
    reference front();
    const_reference front() const;
    linkedlist& operator=(const linkedlist& l);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    void push_back(const element_type& x);
    void push_front(const element_type& x);
    void sort();

    explicit linkedlist(unsigned int n);
    void check() const;
    void rcheck() const;


private:
    struct Node
    {
        element_type elem;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
};

linkedlist::linkedlist()
{
    head = new Node;
    tail = new Node;
    head->next = tail;
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    tail->prev = head;
    size = 0;
}
```

...

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03bb01431652abbe)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Why do this in C++ ? In C, no problem but in C++ you have `list` ! Why typedef in C++ ? Why don't you use a template ? Why do you use NULL and not `nullptr`. Why not use init list in constructor ?

Comment: @Ryan: You failed to include the code that actually triggers the error. The code you posted so far will not trigger it. Most likely reason for the error is what Eugene describes in his answer. But the code you posted does not include anything like that.

Comment: You should provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will allow others to easily reproduce your error. At the moment we'd have to add in some extra code that may or may not be consistent with what you have omitted and probably is the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer for you: if your `reference` is defined inside the class, you need to include class name in the return type of the member function definitions when they are defined outside the class. E.g.

```
linkedlist::reference linkedlist::back(){/*...*/}
```

I cannot guess why `Node` is also a problem because you don't show any code using it.